# Style(highlight/bold) a group of items in combo/select box using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a select box with a list of items which is ordered by two condition, first based on date and next alphabetical. I need to differentiate both group by highlighting one. That is styling only a group of items in bold. What is the best way to do it using Css and jquery?

Comment: Without examples or more pointers it's hard to be specific.  But with jQuery styling a set of things is easy.  (you'd need a css selector to identify your subset of elements, and then you can add other css elements http://api.jquery.com/css/ )  Note: styling a select control can vary across browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Enables a lot of improvements and even more features that you could appreciate.